# interest of docker create volume command?

Tags: docker, volume

i actually play a lot with docker,
and i really don't understand the interest of using the command

```
docker volume create <volume>
```

In fact, doing this

```
docker volume create my_data
docker run --rm -ti -v my_data:/src bash
```

and only this

```
docker run --rm -ti -v my_data:/src bash
```

give exactly the same result, as, in the two scenarii, docker

1. creates the volume
2. makes the mapping perfectly

So: what is the interest of the 'create' command ?

Comment: It's parallel to `docker volume rm` and `docker network create`, and you occasionally need non-default volume options.  But if you don't need it, as you note, `docker run` will create a named volume if it doesn't exist, so it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Maze already said, you can specify non-default volume options with the `docker volume create` command, such as labels, a custom driver and options for this driver. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create) has some interesting examples:

> For example, the following creates a tmpfs volume called foo with a size of 100 megabyte and uid of 1000.
>
> ```bash
> docker volume create --driver local \
>    --opt type=tmpfs \
>    --opt device=tmpfs \
>    --opt o=size=100m,uid=1000 \
>    foo
> ```
>
> Another example that uses btrfs:
>
> ```bash
> docker volume create --driver local \
>    --opt type=btrfs \
>    --opt device=/dev/sda2 \
>    foo
> ```
>
> Another example that uses nfs to mount the /path/to/dir in rw mode from 192.168.1.1:
>
> ```bash
> docker volume create --driver local \
>    --opt type=nfs \
>    --opt o=addr=192.168.1.1,rw \
>    --opt device=:/path/to/dir \
>    foo
> ```

Comment: @David Maze. thanks for clear and exhaustiv response.